# Puppeteer - for loop doens't continue to second iteration after page.goBack()

Tags: node.js, for-loop, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am built a for loop to save page states using values of a list

```
if (await elementIsVisible(frame, fundSubAccountSelector.join(','))) {
  const sel = '#TRNcontainer01 > table > tbody > tr > td.TRNdado > select.TRNselect > option'
  const list = await frame.evaluate((sel) => {
    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel))
    const links = elements.map(element => {
      return element.value
    })
    return links
  }, sel)
  list.shift()
  for (const value of list) {
    console.log(value)
    await frame.select('select[name="opcao"]', value)
    await frame.$eval('input[name="xsub"]', el => el.click())
    await frame.waitFor(fundDetailsSelector.join(','))
    parseAssetCode = parseAssets.FUND_INFO_DETAILS
    console.log('COMECANDO A SALVAR')
    await savePageState(
      this.crawlingData,
      frame,
      `detail-PA${parseAssetCode}-${value}-${investmentObject.name.trim().toLowerCase()}`
    )
    console.log('SALVOU')
    page.goBack()
    console.log('voltouuu')
  }
  return this.parseProducer.produce(await getFrameOrPageContent(frame), parseAssetCode)
```

The first iteration works well.

The problem is that when i finish the page.goBack() and the browser returns to the previous page, the loop doesn't continue (example: the console.log(value) isnt printed for the second value of the list)

Someone can help me?

Comment: Move the `page.goBack()` outside of the loop?

Comment: I need to select a dropdown value, continue to the next page, save the page state, then go back, select the second dropdown value, continue to the next page..... if i move the page.goBack() outside the loop it will result a error not found of the select button, because this button is in the previous page

Comment: It seems this should be `await page.goBack()`.